# Node/Angular App - Is a 404 Code Possible in Angular Routes?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I just looked at the crawl stats on my web app, and notice that the Google Crawler attempts hitting URLs that don't exist, neither I have any links for - for example:

`https://www.example.com/-/results/k/Laptop+Notebook/`

and

`https://www.example.com/dasdhkjdsa7di3hdd`

Now when i look at the stats I see the the Cache hit is miss which makes sense however the status code is 200, which I'm thinking should ideally be 404.

Now on the Angular side, in my routes file, at the end I have the code:

```
.otherwise(
    {redirectTo:'/'}
  )
```

So when these random URLs are redirected. However how do I send a 404 code along with it?

I'm wondering is it actually possible, i.e. wouldn't i need to do this on my Node server side. I've attempted the following - however I get an issue.

If i place the res.status(404) code BEFORE the section to handle HTML5Mode Urls, then once a 404 error is displayed, if i go back to a working url (other than the homepage), it incorrectly displays the 404.

If I place the res.status(404) code AFTER, then the Angular `otherwise` takes over and simply redirects to `/`

```
app.use(express.static('site'));

//For Angular HTML5Mode Urls
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
});

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
 res.status(404).send("Sorry that page doesn't exist!");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to do it on the server side?

Comment: As i need Angular to direct and use specific controllers at the front end. Also as I grow my site, how would that node static folder what new pages have been created?